# How to query for a list of associated records using Rails 4 + PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
Question.rb
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer.rb
  belongs_to :question
end
```

What I want to do is get the most recent 10 Answers, and show a list of "Recently Answered Questions"

If I query for `Answer.last(10)`, that provides the answers, How somehow translate the recent answers into a list of `@questions` I can render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> show a list of "Recently Answered Questions"

You're approaching it from the wrong angle, you should be querying `questions` table:

```
@questions = Question.joins(:answers)
                     .group('questions.id, answers.created_at')
                     .order('answers.created_at DESC')
                     .limit(10)
```

This will fire a ***single*** db query and instantly return you 10 recent ***questions with answers***.

Comment: and `map(&:answer)` :)))

Comment: @Ilya if I got the OP correctly, he wants to list answered questions, not answers

Comment: `get the most recent 10 Answers`

Comment: Correct. I'm looking for a list of the questions that were recently answered. Thanks

Comment: This is great. One problem is that if the last 5 answers were for the same question, this query is now listing that question 5 times. Is there a way to make this unique recently answered questions? Thanks

Comment: @AnApprentice sure, sorry for the missing part of the query. Let me edit it. adding a `GROUP BY` would solve it for you (see the `.group('questions.id')` part)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko "::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "answers.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... "questions"."id" GROUP BY questions.id  ORDER BY answers.cr"

Comment: actually just tried the update, it still results in duplicate questions being listed...

Comment: @AnApprentice what if you add `.uniq` to the end of the query?